# php Session variable lost between pages with a form submit

Tags: php, forms, session, session-variables, data-loss

I was wondering if anyone could help me.

If I am on the page details.php (code below) there is a form with a submit button (amongst other things).

When the form's submit button is clicked, you are taken to process_tenant.php.

The problem is the session variable valid_user doesn't seem to come with it. I have session_start() at the start of both pages and the session variable is definitely set and never overwritten on details.php

Anyone able to tell me why?

**details.php**

```
<?php
session_start();

    $_SESSION['valid_user'] = 'admin';

    echo $_SESSION['valid_user'];       //This prints out admin 
?>

<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
        ...
    </head>

    <body>
        ...

        <form action='process_tenant.php' method='POST'>
            ...
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

**process_tenant.php**

```
<?php
   session_start();

   if (isset($_SESSION['valid_user']))
   {
       echo 'heya';          //This does not print
   }

   echo 'hi' . $_SESSION['valid_user'];    //This just prints 'hi'
?>

...
```

Comment: Have you destroyed the session using session_destroy();

Comment: Nope, nowhere. I was wondering if it could be a php configuration problem? As there doesn't seem to be anything wrong with the code.

Comment: Fixed the problem thanks. I wasn't destorying the session but I was overwritting valid_user with ""

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Config.php

```
<?php
ob_start();
session_start();
$_SESSION['valid_user'] = admin;
?>
```

Details.php

```
<?php
include('Config.php');
?>
```

process_tenant.php

```
<?php
include('Config.php');

if (isset($_SESSION['valid_user']))
{
     echo 'heya';
}
echo 'hi' . $_SESSION['valid_user'];
?>
```

Comment: Thanks but adding ob_start() doesn't seem to make a difference.

Comment: That doesn't make a difference. It is just the same code written in a different file.

Comment: Have you destroy session somewhere?

Comment: I've not destroyed the session anywhere

Comment: why was this answer accepted? what solved this issue?

Answer (score 0):

In details.php the value admin doesn't equate to anything. It needs to be either a variable or a string or some kind of valid type otherwise it will be unset.

Try changing your code to this:

```
$_SESSION['valid_user'] = 'admin';
```

Comment: It actually gets the value from a database but I just put = admin for simplicity. But yes, I did forget the '' in my question. Thanks

Answer (score -1):

start only once, ie use `session_start()` only once, remove from `process_tenant.php` and let me know then once done.

Comment: session_start() does need to be called once for every PHP call. Since he isn't including the details.php file in the process_tenant.php file he will need to call session_start().

Comment: If you don't include session_start() at the top of both pages it throws a massive error. You definitely need session_start().